# Starter issues on ford f150

Tags: ford, starting, f-150

i have replaced my starter 2 times in my 99 f150 4.2. Smoke came from the starter the first time. Now the starter just spins

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Are you doing these repairs yourself?  Is this happening over time?  Or did you go through two starters during the same repair?  If same repair can you manually turn the crankshaft (Is the engine frozen?). If not, possible flywheel/flex plate outer teeth wear issues?